# ionic Nothing happened after lint finished when build or run

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I hope I can get a bit of a clue in here. I did my research but I cant find the answer. I saw two previous similar question with no answer also. The problem is: whenever I do:

ionic cordova run android

ionic cordova run ios

ionic cordova build android

ionic cordova build ios

the CLI stopped after “Lint finished”. No error, nothing.

Ionic serve can do fine in browser.

it is also happened when i started new default blank project so I know this is not project issue, but my environtment.

Below are output of ionic info:
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 5.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 4.0.0, ios
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.0, (and 10 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v6.11.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10

Please give me idea where to look at. Is my node outdated or something?

Comment: I think that my problem is I installed in several way (using npm, package installer, brew), so I got lost track which is currently used by my env.

Comment: i use ionic 4.2.1
npm 6.4.1
cordova 5.0.0
nodeJS v6.11.2
ionic-angular 3.9.2
ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms : android 4.0.0
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
OS: Windows 10

Comment: Finally, i uninstall ionic 
> npm uninstall cordova ionic
And install again @latest
And > ionic cordova platform rm android && ionic cordova platform add android
After that i write the command 
> ionic cordova build android and it work fine